# On GitBash (on Windows 8) how do you open files?

Tags: git-bash

I'm working on One Month Rails and it says to type into Git Bash the command "open ." to open files, but its not working for me  (though the other commands pwd cd are).  Is this cause he's using a mac and I'm on Windows? Is there another command for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

On the Mac (using the Terminal app) you can open a folder using:

```
open .
```

On Windows / PC (using the GitBash app) the same command would be:

```
start .
```